# STS version nomenclature

Tags: spring, release-management, spring-tool-suite

http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts

I am trying to download new STS tool. On the above site I find 
Milestone Version and Release Version. Can anyone tell me what these terms mean? Which is Users version to be used and is completely developed and not under-development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release version is the one you want, "release" means it's considered to be done and ready for the public. "Milestone" means it's a stable checkpoint made available for community developers to test. You'd pick the milestone one if there are new features or bugfixes you want to try out that haven't been included in a release yet.